# Отсчет на PHP до 100

Tags: php, веб-программирование, phpstorm, время, таймер

как сделать так, чтобы был отсчет от 0 до 100 одного элемента, т.е. не так чтобы просто на странице у меня были выведены цифры от 0 до 100 в линию или в столбец, **А чтобы с каждой секундой этот один элемент изменялся на месте , типа 0, через секунду 1, далее 2, 3..и так до 100**, медленно как обычный секундомер. Если такое возможно, то можно ли установить время через которое цифра будет меняться, типа ещё медленнее или быстрее шел отсчет?

P.S. надеюсь смог объяснить что хотел))

Comment: php выполняется на сервере. вам это, я понимаю, надо на клиенте - в браузере? воспользуйтесь javascript'ом

Comment: js [setInterval()](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval#setinterval)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку речь заходит о вебе, то PHP вам не помощник. Дополнительную красоту нужно наводить через js и `setTimeout`.

Если же вы хотите запустить например в консоле скрипт, который realtime бы отсчитывал, то тут вам помогла бы тема буфера вывода:

```php
ob_start();


for($i = 0;$i<100;$i++)
{
    echo $i;
    ob_flush();
    sleep(1);
}


ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: спасибо большое, этот код он через минуту мне от 1 до 59 в строчку выдает.
Значит в PHP без JS я никак не могу это сделать?

Comment: ещё раз, если мы разговариваем про веб-приложение - да.

Comment: Ок, Спасиб! @Alex Khonko